# How to rotate an object around any line instead of X Y Z or through origin of coordinate

Tags: javascript, three.js, rotation

[image]

There are two boxes, they have no relationship, the first (center is the origin) rotate on the black line and the second (the other) rotate on the yellow line simultaneously！

Create two mesh:

```
geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(50, 50, 50);
material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();

mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
mesh2.position.x = 100;
mesh3 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

scene.add(mesh2);
scene.add(mesh3);
```

Create two lines:

```
var geometryLine = new THREE.Geometry();
geometryLine.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 80, 0));
geometryLine.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 80, 180));
var line1 = new THREE.LineSegments(geometryLine, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color: 0xffffff}));
scene.add(line1);

var geometryLine2 = new THREE.Geometry();
geometryLine2.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(150, 0, 0));
geometryLine2.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(150, 0, 180));
var line2 = new THREE.LineSegments(geometryLine2, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color: 0xffff00}));
scene.add(line2);
```

Every time when use rotation, it just rotates on X Y Z or through the origin.

```
mesh3.rotation.x += 0.01;
mesh2.rotation.y += 0.02;

// I don't know how it works about rotation on specified line
```

But that is not what I want? Then how to rotate on the specified line SIMULTANEOUSLY! I am a newer. Hope the questions can be solved!

Comment: Your code should already rotate the blocks simultaneously. I recommend reducing the problem to one block and one line, then expanding to two. BUT, are you trying to rotate a block _around_ a line, or are you trying to rotate a block at the line's position with the line as its axis of rotation?

Comment: Ok, with the line as its axis of rotation, maybe it is not so difficult, like what I  mentioned above(mesh2.rotation.y += 0.02)  if the line is not the axis???  And I use the (mesh2.position.set(x,y,z)), I think maybe it can also revise its rotation axies, BUT it doesn't matter! It drives me crazy!

Comment: If the origin is the coordinate, there is no problem, we can use API rotateonAxis(axis, angle). If not, I have no ideal!

Comment: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/50exaqjg/) did you want to achieve this result?

Comment: The fiddle provided by prisoner849 is what I meant by rotating the box _around_ a line. To make it rotate with the line as the box's location and axis of rotation, simply comment out the line `cubeGeom.translate(0, -cubeTranslate, 0);`. If neither of these is what you're looking for, we'll need a better description.

Comment: Thanks I have find a better solution to use *.dae. And the newly collada 1.5 supports kinematics! So it will get easier!